# Symfony - Get service by value

Tags: php, symfony, service

i need to get a service depending on a variable definend in runtime. The value can be 1-4 and every value has it own Service to handle it.

What is the best way to do this ? I thougt about a factory but i never used one before.

Thanks in advance.

***EDIT:*** Thanks for the answers. Here is a bit more detailed example.

I have different classes for different business cases. 
Order, Termination, Storno and Change. The classes extend one Baseclass and have some methods with different implementations, for example to handle responses.
I get those services inside a Command. When a message is found, i determine which business case it is and then i need to get the correct service to handle it.
I could do a switch/case and then $this->container->get[.....], but i feel like that is a very "ugly" solution.

Comment: Please expand the question. What do you want to get the service for? do you want to inject it to another service or get it in controller. And at what point is the variable defined?
 is it user input or decided by the application etc. Depending on the use there may be different approaches to accomplish this.

Comment: I tried to make my question a bit more clear.

Comment: Move the switch statement into a factory class so in your command you might have something like $item = $this->container->get('item.factory')->create($itemValue).  The ugly bits will be hidden away in your factory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the service-names are marked as public (so you can use `$this->get($name)` in a controller), you can build it as you would any other string

```
public function doAction($request, $serviceNumber)
{
    // get the ?serviceNumber=1|2|3|4, or a default if not set
    $serviceNumber = $request->request->getInt('serviceNumber', 1);

    // name.of.service1 or name.of.service2, ...
    $serviceName = "name.of.service" . $serviceNumber;
    $service = $this->get($serviceName); 
    // etc ...
```

You may also want to check that the service exists first - `if (!$this->has($serviceName)) { throw new \Exception('...'); }`